# How to do an action while there's still values in the array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm solving this hackerrank challenge called Cut the Sticks, but I cant find a way to do this action while there are still values in the array.

The problem says that given an array, find the minimum element, subtract it from all the elements in the array while they're different from 0 and print the number of subtractions made.

Then with the new array with the subtractions made, repeat the same, find the minimum and subtract it until you can't make any subtraction.

This is my code. I've tried making the sum of all the elements in the array and then doing the next steps while the sum is not 0, but I can't get it to work. It displays wildly large numbers infinitely.

Can you please help me with this maybe simple task?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt(); // Numero de sticks
    int arr[] = new int[n]; // Arreglo Contenedor de longitud de sticks
    for (int arr_i = 0; arr_i < n; arr_i++) {
        arr[arr_i] = in.nextInt(); // Longitud de los sticks
    }
    int cut_counter = 0;

    int min = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < min) {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(min);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (arr[j] != 0) {
            arr[j] = arr[j] - min;
            cut_counter += 1;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(cut_counter);
    /*System.out.println(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
    }*/

 }
}
```

Comment: Just initialize a new array.

Comment: Link to the question?

Comment: The problem happens at some point when the minimum value in the array is 0.  This minimum value is then subtracted from the rest of the elements in the array, with no change in their values (because any number minus 0 is that same number).  However, you are still counting that subtraction, and so the count of subtractions never reduces.  Perhaps you should check that the value you are subtracting is never less than 1.

Comment: Also make sure that min is never set to 0 when you do the initialization of min in the statement "min = arr[0]";

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cut-the-sticks This is the challenge

Answer (score 1):

Some small modifications to your code that might be what you need:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter number of numbers: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt(); // Numero de sticks
    int arr[] = new int[n]; // Arreglo Contenedor de longitud de sticks
    System.out.println("Enter " + n + " numbers: ");
    for (int arr_i = 0; arr_i < n; arr_i++) {
        arr[arr_i] = in.nextInt(); // Longitud de los sticks
    }

    int cut_counter;
    do {

        cut_counter = 0;

        boolean min_set = false;
        int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (arr[i]!=0) {
                min=arr[i];
                min_set=true;
            }
        }
        if (!min_set)
            break;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (arr[i] < min && arr[i] != 0) {
                min = arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Min=" + min);
        //System.out.println(min);
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (arr[j] != 0 && min > 0 ) {
                arr[j] = arr[j] - min;
                cut_counter += 1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("cut_counter=" + cut_counter);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    } while (cut_counter > 0);

}
```